Can I do weighting on continuous variables?
I have two datasets collected in 2018 and 2023. I was going to check if there's any difference between the two datasets, but the ratio of sex and family size was different from each other (significantly more females and more family sizes in 2023), and that is how it all started.
Since those two distributions are different, I am trying to weigh on a second dataset (i.e., 2023). But the thing is, the variable I would like to weigh is continuous variables (Family size, from 0 to 10).
My original plan is to examine quartiles. This way, I thought I could calculate weights based on the data distribution, ensuring that the weights reflect the proportional representation of each quartile.
But the data is not normally distributed which means I couldn't divide the values based on quartiles. I did log transformation and other things but is still the same.
Are there any other ways?
Thank you in advance!!

Welcome to Cross Validated! If you have that the sex ratio and family size ratio are different between the two years, isn't that evidence that the datasets from the two years are different? If that isn't sufficient to answer your ultimate question(s), perhaps you can say more about what you want to do.

Sorry! I should have explained that. We are not interested in sex or family size. (Considering it happened due to sampling error) Our primary interest is what drives certain things other than the sex and family size variables.

So you have a different outcome variable other than sex and family size? And different predictors? If you have sufficient sample size, you might just fit a linear model with sex and family size as predictor variables to account for their effect on your outcome, and include any other variable of interest to look for its effect.
It's a little difficult to tell what you mean here though, so it would be helpful to share an example of some data.
